# Recibir datos de 4 activities en una sola activity

Tags: java, android

Tengo 4 `activities` en las cuales ingreso datos y quiero recibir esos mismos datos en una sola `activity`.

**Primera activity de registro de datos:**

```
Intent Register = new Intent(this,Window_Configuracion.class);
etConstanteK = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConstanteK);
etDC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDC);

Register.putExtra("K_To_Objetivo",etConstanteK.getText().toString() );
Register.putExtra("DC_To_Objetivo",etDC.getText().toString() );

Toast toastconfirmed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Se han registrado exitosamente las variables", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toastconfirmed.show();

startActivity(Register);
```

**Segunda activity de registro de datos:**

```
Intent Register = new Intent(this, Window_Configuracion.class);
etHP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHP);
etDEG = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDEG);

Register.putExtra("HP_To_Objetivo",etHP.getText().toString() );
Register.putExtra("DEG_To_Objetivo",etDEG.getText().toString() );

Toast toastconfirmed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Se han registrado exitosamente las variables", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toastconfirmed.show();

 startActivity(Register);
```

**Tercera activity de registro de datos:**

```
Intent Register = new Intent(this, Window_Configuracion.class);
etGravedad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtGravedad);

Register.putExtra("Gravedad_To_Objetivo",etGravedad.getText().toString() );

Toast toastconfirmed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Se ha registrado exitosamente la variable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toastconfirmed.show();
startActivity(Register);
```

**Cuarta activity de registro de datos:**

```
Intent Register = new Intent(this, Window_Configuracion.class);
etMasa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMasa);

Register.putExtra("Masa_To_Objetivo",etMasa.getText().toString() );

Toast toastconfirmed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Se ha registrado exitosamente la variable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toastconfirmed.show();

startActivity(Register);
```

**Activity en la que necesito obtener todos los datos:**

```
Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
txtConstanteK = datos.getString("K_To_Objetivo");
txtDC = datos.getString("DC_To_Objetivo");
txtGravedad= datos.getString("Gravedad_To_Objetivo");
txtHP = datos.getString("HP_To_Objetivo");
txtDEG = datos.getString("DEG_To_Objetivo");
txtMasa = datos.getString("Masa_To_Objetivo");
```

Utilizo el método `bundle` pero siempre me marca error.

Comment: Alonso, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Toma en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

> - Únicamente los datos que envíes en un `Intent` son los que recibirá la Activity que deseas abrir.
> - Si deseas recibir todos los valores, los tendrías que enviar en un `Intent`.

En cuanto al error al recibir los datos se puede generar al recibir valores nulos, para esto puedes agregar un parámetro default que se asignaría en caso de no recibir valor: `getString(<key> , <valor default>)`.

Puedes realizar este cambio asignando una cadena vacia como valor default para evitar posibles problemas:

```
Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
txtConstanteK = datos.getString("K_To_Objetivo", "");
txtDC = datos.getString("DC_To_Objetivo", "");
txtGravedad= datos.getString("Gravedad_To_Objetivo", "");
txtHP = datos.getString("HP_To_Objetivo", "");
txtDEG = datos.getString("DEG_To_Objetivo", "");
txtMasa = datos.getString("Masa_To_Objetivo", "");
```